# How to fix issue with tkinter checkboxes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to make a python(2.7) Cafe System. I created most of the functions just one function It is supposed to after I click the check button to open up the entry. Just when I click the check box button it won't open does anyone know why?

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
import time
import datetime

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1350x750+0+0")
root.title("Cafe Management System")
root.configure(background='black')

Tops = Frame(root, width=1350, height=100, bd=14, relief="raise")
Tops.pack(side=TOP)

f1 = Frame(root, width=900, height=650, bd=8, relief="raise")
f1.pack(side=LEFT)

f2 = Frame(root, width=440, height=650, bd=8, relief="raise")
f2.pack(side=RIGHT)

f1a = Frame(f1, width=900, height=320, bd=6, relief="raise")
f1a.pack(side=TOP)

f2a = Frame(f1, width=900, height=320, bd=6, relief = "raise")
f2a.pack(side=BOTTOM)

ft2 = Frame(f2, width= 440,height=450,bd=12,relief="raise")
ft2.pack(side=TOP)
fb2 = Frame(f2, width=440, height=250, bd=16, relief="raise")
fb2.pack(side=BOTTOM)

f1aa = Frame(f1a, width=400, height=330, bd=16, relief="raise")
f1aa.pack(side=LEFT)
f1ab = Frame(f1a, width=400, height=330, bd=16, relief="raise")
f1ab.pack(side=RIGHT)

f2aa = Frame(f2a, width=450, height=330, bd=14, relief="raise")
f2aa.pack(side=LEFT)

f2ab = Frame(f2a, width=450, height=330, bd=14, relief="raise")
f2ab.pack(side=RIGHT)
Tops.configure(background='black')
f1.configure(background='black')
f2.configure(background='black')
lblInfo = Label(Tops, font=('arial', 70, 'bold'), text="Cafe Management")
lblInfo.grid(row=0, column=0)
#===============================Functions============================
def qExit():
    root.destroy()

def Reset():
    PaidTax.set("")
    SubTotal.set("")
    TotalCost.set("")
    CostofDrinks.set("")
    CostofCakes.set("")
    ServiceCharge.set("")
    txtReciept.delete("1.0",END)

    E_Latta.set("0")
    E_Coffee_Cake.set("0")
#===============================Variables============================
var1=IntVar()

DateofOrder = StringVar()
Reciept_Ref = StringVar()
PaidTax = StringVar()
SubTotal = StringVar()
TotalCost = StringVar()
CostofCakes=StringVar()
CostofDrinks=StringVar()
ServiceCharge=StringVar()

E_Latta = StringVar()
E_Coffee_Cake=StringVar()
E_Coffee_Cake.set("0")

DateofOrder.set(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
#=========================DRINKS======================
Latta = Checkbutton(f1ab, text="Latte \t", variable = var1, onvalue = 1,    offvalue = 0,
               font=('arial',18,'bold')).grid(row=0, sticky=W)
#=======================Enter Widget For Cakes=================
txtLatta = Entry(f1aa, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bd=8, width=6, justify='left', textvariable=E_Coffee_Cake, state=DISABLED)
txtLatta.grid(row=0, column=1)
#===========================================================Check b
def chkbutton_value():
    if (var1.get() == 1):
        txtLatta.configure(state=NORMAL)
    elif var1.get()==0:
        txtLatta.configure(state=DISABLED)
        E_Latta.set("0")
#===========================================================Check btns
var1.set(0)

txtLatta.configure(state=DISABLED)
#=======================================Infomation====
lblReciept = Label(ft2, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), text="Reciept", bd=2).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W,)
txtReciept = Text(fb2,font=('arial',11,'bold'), bd=8, width=59)
txtReciept.grid(row=1, column=0)

#========================================Items
lblCostofDrinks=Label(f2aa,font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), text="Cost of Drinks", bd=8)
lblCostofDrinks.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
txtCostofDrinks=Entry(f2aa, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'),  bd=8,
                 insertwidth=2,justify='left', textvariable=CostofDrinks)
txtCostofDrinks.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

lblCostofCakes=Label(f2aa,font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), text="Cost of Cakes", bd=8)
lblCostofCakes.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
txtCostofCakes=Entry(f2aa, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bd=8,
                insertwidth=2,justify='left',textvariable=CostofCakes)
txtCostofCakes.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

lblServiceCharge=Label(f2aa,font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), text="Service Charge", bd=8)
lblServiceCharge.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
txtServiceCharge=Entry(f2aa, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bd=8,
                  insertwidth=2, justify='left')
txtServiceCharge.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
#========================================Payment Info===================================
lblPaidTax=Label(f2ab,font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), text="Tax", bd=8)
lblPaidTax.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
txtPaidTax=Entry(f2ab, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bd=8,
            insertwidth=2, justify='left', textvariable=PaidTax)
txtPaidTax.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

lblSubTotal=Label(f2ab,font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), text="Sub Total", bd=8)
lblSubTotal.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
txtSubTotal=Entry(f2ab, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bd=8,
             insertwidth=2, justify='left', textvariable=SubTotal)
txtSubTotal.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

lblTotalCost=Label(f2ab,font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), text="Total", bd=8)
lblTotalCost.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
txtTotalCost=Entry(f2ab, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bd=8,
              insertwidth=2, justify='left', textvariable=TotalCost)
txtTotalCost.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

CostofDrinks.set("")
CostofCakes.set("")
#========================================Buttons=======================
btnTotal = Button(fb2,padx=16,pady=1,bd=4,fg="black",font=('arial',    16,'bold'), width=5,
             text="Total ").grid(row=3, column=1)

btnReciept = Button(fb2,padx=16,pady=1,bd=4,fg="black",font=('arial', 16,'bold'), width=5,
             text="Reciept ").grid(row=3, column=2)

btnReset = Button(fb2,padx=16,pady=1,bd=4,fg="black",font=('arial', 16,'bold'), width=5,
             text="Reset ", command=Reset).grid(row=3, column=3)

btnExit = Button(fb2,padx=16,pady=1,bd=4,fg="black",font=('arial', 16,'bold'), width=5,
              text="Exit ",command=qExit).grid(row=3, column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @cricket_007   When I created this program my goal was that when the checkboxes became checked the entry instead of being disabled it would turn into a accessible entry so I could type and stuff could turn up. However when I uncheck it it becomes and stays disabled. I put all the code that would make this function available but it still doesn't work

Comment: You could reduce this code to 1/10th of its current size not even in terms of a MCVE but in general.

Comment: def chkbutton_value():
    if (var1.get() == 1):
        txtLatta.configure(state=NORMAL)
    elif var1.get()==0:
        txtLatta.configure(state=DISABLED)
        E_Latta.set("0")

txtLatta = Entry(f1aa, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bd=8, width=6,         justify='left', textvariable=E_Coffee_Cake, state=DISABLED)
txtLatta.grid(row=0, column=1)

Comment: @Pythonista             Thats the code it is supposed to when I uncheck the check button the entry becomes normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking some time on this one I noticed several formatting problems. However I am just going to answer the question about the checkbox issue.

You need to change your creation of each checkbox to include `command = chkbutton_value`.

Take a look at how I would create your Latta check button.

```
Latta = Checkbutton(f1ab, text="Latte \t", onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0,
               font=('arial',18,'bold'), variable = var1, command = chkbutton_value)
```

NOTE: you need to make sure the function `chkbutton_value():` is before the creation of your check buttons because you will get a error otherwise. `NameError: name 'chkbutton_value' is not defined`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Sorry I didn't notice that at the start.

Comment: Sure thing :) Glad I can help.